# Create batch file to block specific programs

Tags: batch-file

How to create an autorun batch file to block/close portable programs?

For example:
if (xxx.exe is running)
then (close it immediately OR block access to internet)

Thank you.

I have tested this batch command:

```
@echo off
:TOP
    tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq taskmgr.exe" /FO | grep taskmgr.exe
        if ERRORLEVEL == 0 taskkill /f /im taskmgr.exe
GOTO TOP
```

but it's failed to run, what is the problem?

Comment: in case the programs is not running from fixed path, like: c:/xxx.exe then next time running at d:/abc/xxx.exe

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, in batch anyways.

You could edit registry keys for certain files to stop them from being run but this would be system wide, not just for portable programs.

There are too many variables to consider, and this really isn't something you can do in batch.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you have any suggestion? Because my colleague always use my laptop to playing games with their portable games. Firewall doesn't help much as it's portable apps.

Comment: I don't really, sorry. The only thing I can think of that would stop ALL portable apps from being run would be to disable the use of usb drives.